# How to find dependency of a column

Tags: oracle

In oracle how can we find all the foreign key of a column.

Meaning to say in table info i have id column.

So how can I find who is referring id column.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_constraints 
WHERE r_constraint_name= '<constraint_name>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the constraint name for your column, and then use the query below

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   all_constraints
WHERE  r_constraint_name = ConstraintName;
```